# Websites in Asp.Net does not work in Windows Vista

Tags: asp.net, windows, internet-explorer, windows-vista

I have a strange question!
I have developed a website in asp.net webforms, I've tested this website in IE7, IE8, Ie9 (RC), Firefox, Chrome and Safari, in Windows XP and Windows 7. Everything works fine.

But in Internet Explorer in Windows Vista, does not working. The website opens in browser, but when the application needs a postback it does not work. I don't know why it is happening. If someone could suggest something to accomplish this? I appretiate!

Thank you!
Att,

Comment: What version of IE where they running? Did you check for javascript errors?

Comment: You'll need to do better than that. What doesn't work, exactly? And what does not working mean in this case? What did you try and what did it do? As far as I'm concerned, the OS isn't important for website function like the browser is, unless you are doing something unusual on the client side.

Comment: It's crystal ball time again!

Comment: Also, be certain that the problem is Vista in general, and not some specific Vista installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A failed postback could be due to a javascript error.   Have you tried using the Javascript console (Shift+F12) in IE8, or using Firebug Lite in versions lower than IE8?   Could you turn off surpressing javascript error notifications to see if this presents the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Highly doubt it's the OS... Check your internet options...

Comment: More than use Mac OS and Linux combined!